# Alias name in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone please say how to create an alias name for a table in a snowflake?

```
sample table:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE USER.EMPLOYEE(
    EMPNO CHAR(6 ) COLLATE 'en_US-upper-rtrim' NOT NULL,
    FIRSTNME VARCHAR(12 ) COLLATE 'en_US-upper-rtrim' NOT NULL,
    MIDINIT CHAR(1 ) COLLATE 'en_US-upper-rtrim' NULL,
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(15 ) COLLATE 'en_US-upper-rtrim' NOT NULL,
    WORKDEPT CHAR(3 ) COLLATE 'en_US-upper-rtrim' NULL,
    PHONENO CHAR(4 ) COLLATE 'en_US-upper-rtrim' NULL,
    HIREDATE DATE NULL,
    JOB CHAR(8 ) COLLATE 'en_US-upper-rtrim' NULL,
    EDLEVEL SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    SEX CHAR(1 ) COLLATE 'en_US-upper-rtrim' NULL,
    BIRTHDATE DATE NULL,
    SALARY NUMBER(9,2) NULL,
    BONUS NUMBER(9,2) NULL,
    COMM NUMBER(9,2) NULL
);
```

Alias:

```
CREATE ALIAS "USER"."EMP" FOR TABLE "USER"." EMPLOYEE"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are searching for **SYNONYM/ALIAS**, they are not supported by Snowflake.

```
CREATE SYNONYM EMP FOR USER.EMPLOYEE;
```

Reference: [Migrating Oracle Database to Snowflake: Reference Manual - APPENDIX D](https://resources.snowflake.com/migration-guides/migrating-oracle-database-to-snowflake-reference-manual)

---

Depending on requirements VIEW could be used instead:

```
CREATE VIEW USER.EMP
AS
SELECT *
FROM  USER.EMPLOYEE;
```

Comment: Thanks, But can you please say how to create the alias for the table employee
for example,
"CREATE ALIAS "USER"."EMP" FOR TABLE "USER"." EMPLOYEE";"

Comment: @sandy https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=statements-create-alias `The CREATE ALIAS statement defines an alias for a module, nickname, sequence, table, view, or another alias.`  **`Aliases are also known as synonyms.`**

Comment: @sandy Alias/synonym is the same concept, not supported by Snowflake as of today.