# In snowflake, is there way re-share like a symbolic link?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I currently have data sources that are being consumed by a lot of data consumers. I am now given a new set of data sources to replace existing ones. But I want this new sources to be named like previous data sources but pointed to new data sources. Like a symbolic link in Linux. Is there such a feature in snowflake? Like a symbolic table or db link?

I know I can use a view to wrap this table but there’s a performance issue when using a view especially when it’s a billion records.

Comment: [Alias name in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68873647/5070879)

Comment: Create External table can be one option for you

Comment: Why do you think there is a performance issue with views?

Comment: You should not have any performance issues with a view unless her definition requires high ressource consumption. If it's just a select from your new source you will not have this problem.

If performance with your views remains problematic then you can have a look on materialized views.